# Property of the conjugate transpose matrix with inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, transpose

I'm trying to prove that for a certain matrix $A$, and its conjugate transpose $A^*$, we have $⟨Ax,y⟩=⟨x,A^*y⟩$, where $⟨⟩$ represent the inner product. So here it's simply the dot product in $R^n$.

Does anyone have an idea of how to prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: conjugate transpose and dot product in $\mathbb R^n$ is kind of irritating ...

Answer (score 8):

The inner product (dot product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n$) is defined as
$$ \langle x,y \rangle = x^* y = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \overline{x_k} y_k
$$
Some definitions switch them around ($x^\intercal \overline{y}$) but they are essentially the same.
$$ \langle Ax,y \rangle = (Ax)^* y = x^* A^* y = \langle x, A^* y \rangle
$$
Since you are using $\mathbb{R}^n$, the conjugation can be dropped without any problem.

Comment: Can you explain the $(Ax)^*y =x^*A^*y$ step?

Comment: how can $x^\intercal \overline{y}$ be the same as $x^* y$? I think $\overline{x^\intercal}y$ is the same as $x^*y$ by definition, but $\overline{x^\intercal}y$ is a complex conjugate of $x^\intercal \overline{y}$, so they are not the same, are they?