# How to simplify $A^{-1}a\cdot A^Tb$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions, vectors, monotone-functions

Positive real vectors $x,y,x',y'\in\mathbb R^2_+$; $f,g$ are multivariate functions: $f,g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$. Matrix $A\in\mathbb R^{2\times2}$.

Given that $y=Ax$, $y'=Ax'$, $A^Tg(y)=f(x)$, and $(x-x')\cdot(f(x)-f(x'))\leq0$

Prove that $(y-y')\cdot(g(y)-g(y'))\leq 0$.

---

The first step is obviously $(x-x')(f(x)-f(x'))\leq0$ implies $(x-x')\cdot A^T(g(y)-g(y'))\leq0.$

If we furhter assume the invertability of $A$, then$$A^{-1}(y-y')\cdot A^T(g(y)-g(y'))\leq0.$$

It seems that it cannot be further simplified.....

Comment: The only thing left after the first step is to [notice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1684589/property-of-the-conjugate-transpose-matrix-with-inner-product) that $u\cdot A^Tv=Au\cdot v$ for any (real) vectors $u,v$ and (real) matrix $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$(A^{-1} a) \cdot (A^Tb) = (A^Tb)^T(A^{-1}a) = b^TAA^{-1}a = b^Ta = a \cdot b.$$
This completes your proof.

Comment: Readers new to matrices are advised there's a subtle [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation) in this calculation, which we've discussed before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899910/matrix-multiplication-not-associative-when-matrices-are-vectors). It makes the algebra more precise without really being harmful.